# Ayuda con xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Soy nuevo en Xamarin Forms y lo estoy trabajando con VS 2015, este descargo el SDK de android automaticamente, lo que no me queda claro es, como saber cuando empiezo a trabajar, para que versiones de android queda funcional mi aplicación?... es decir pruebo la aplicación en mi celular que es android 5 y funciona bien, pero también funcionaría para Android 4, Android 6 y Android 7, y como logro desarrollar en estas plataformas... Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para tener un mejor entendimiento del manejo de Xamarin con Android te recomiendo estos 2 cortos videos, son muy intuitivos: - Android SDKs: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-6-Managing-Android-SDKs - API level settings: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-11-Understanding-Android-API-Level-Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso de xamarin debe trabajar con las propiedades del proyecto como tal haciendo click derecho en el proyecto, para definir el api minimo segun lo que indica la siguiente URL

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

Despues lo que te queda es compilar y probar en un emulador que tenga una version consistente a la que se quiere estimar compatibilidad, muchas veces con solo tratar de compilar ya se sabe si el codigo programado es o no compatible con x o y version de android